# NASM (assembly) segmentation fault on 2nd loop iteration

Tags: loops, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, cmp

I keep getting a segmentation fault the second time I go through the loop and enter E (intended to exit the loop).  If I enter E the first time, it exits just fine.  Hopefully I'm just being dumb here and someone can suggest an easy fix!

Thanks for your time.

Declarations:

```
segment .bss
        a resd 1
        b resd 1
        op resb 2
```

Main:

```
loop:

    call read_int    ;read two integers, then a char
    mov [a], eax
    call read_int
    mov [b], eax
    call read_char
    call read_char   ;takes newline input

    cmp al, 'E'      ;if char is E, then exit
    je exit

    call loop        ;start over

exit:
    dump_regs 0      ;completes, but then seg faults if the loop has run more than once
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of problems/potential problems right off the bad:

1) when you "call" a subroutine, you generally need to a) update the stack (in your subroutine) and b) clear the stack (after you return).

You haven't shown us "read_int" or "read_char", but I suspect that's probably the case.

2) BAD: `call loop`.  BETTER: `jmp loop`.

You can find some good NASM examples here: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample.shtml

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING. What a dumb mistake on my part. Really appreciate the help!  I'll upvote and check off as soon as my new account allows it.